# Modifying the Command Bar for the Unified Client Interface in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, crm-ribbon-workbench, dynamics-crm-uci

In the new Unified Client Interface for Dynamics 365 I am trying to hide some buttons. Specifically the "Show Chart" and "Appointment" buttons. I am using the Ribbon Workbench 2016. So far I've searched but I don't see any other tool for modifying the command bar.

I create a solution with my entity with metadata only. I then open the solution in Ribbon Workbench 2016. I cannot find these buttons. I've tried using the tabs "Command Bar", "Ribbon", and "Tablet" and cannot see these buttons.

My question: How can I modify the command bar for the Unified Client Interface?

> [image: Command Bar in Unified Client Interface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which entity have you added in your solution?

To hide the button shows you need Activity entity. Once you have activity entity in ribbon workbench you need to select home grid and there you find the buttons.
Also last time I played it activity entity, it was bit tricky as Microsoft does not easily allow to customize activity entity Wrt ribbon.

Comment: Hi AnkUser. I am using the contact entity and the a phone call entity. I will try adding the Activity entity and then follow your instructions. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Hi AnkUser. I created a solution with the Activity entity and then opened it in ribbon workbench 2016. I saw the "Appointment" button and was able to hide it. I still don't see the "Show Chart" button. I am going to try other entities to see if the "Show Chart" button exists there.

Comment: Hi @AnkUser, I found out that for model-driven apps, which is what I am using and didn't mention in my description, that there isn't a way to hide the "Show Chart" button. See this link: [Show Chart Button](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-hide-show-chart-button-in-dynamics/td-p/262728). There is a workaround mentioned where a person adds this line of code: `window.parent.document.getElementById("ShowChartPane").style.display = "none";` However I am not sure where to place this code.

Comment: @glennsep that’s some unsupported script, which may break in future

Answer (score 1):

There are two types:

`Application Ribbon` - common for entities like **Home grid** (buttons like Edit, Deactivate, etc), **Entity form** (buttons like Save, New, etc), **Dashboard** to include superset of basic buttons across the entire application.

`Entity Ribbon` - specific to corresponding entity based functionalities and only for that entity only without disturbing other entities.

Now Microsoft introduced some built-in un-customizable Ribbon buttons like `Show Chart` which is invisible in both ribbons. Unfortunately we have to ignore them for now, as there is only unsupported approach available, which is not recommended.

MS support team in [this community thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/how-to-hide-or-delete-not-required-button/td-p/329606) says:

> Actually, the "Show Chart" button and "Run report" button are both
> built-in buttons within a Model-Driven form or D365 CRM form, which
> could not be hidden or deleted.
>
> In addition, currently, there is no
> way to hidden or delete the "Show Chart" button and "Run report"
> button (built-in buttons) from a Model-Driven form within PowerApps.